# Apache + Tomcat with mod_proxy - redirect to www not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, no-www

I have a problem trying to rewrite the root of my web from **mywebsite.com/mywebsite** to **www.mywebsite.com/mywebsite.**

The problem is related to the use of **mod_proxy to invoke Tomcat**

**File proxy.conf**

```
<ifmodule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <proxy *>
       AddDefaultCharset off
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
    </proxy>

    ProxyVia On 
    ProxyPass /mywebsite ajp://91.222.222.222:8009/mywebsite
    ProxyPassReverse /mywebsite ajp://91.222.222.222:8009/mywebsite

    <location miaplicacion>
        Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </location>
</ifmodule>
```

**File .htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

The point is that the rule works OK if I write **mywebsite.com/something**. In this case it's correctly redirected to **www.mywebsite.com/something**

However It seems as if the proxy has preference over what is written in the rewrite rules. That is to say, when it finds mywebsite.com/mywebsite, instead of rewriting it to www.mywebsite.com/mywebsite and then invoke Tomcat, it calls it inmediately without touching the URL.

Do you know any way to force the rewriting of the URL before proxying to Tomcat?

Comment: yes, remove the ! before www on the first line (and the www. for what you want to do)

Comment: That way the result is the same: when the content after / (mywebsite) is the same as what is between www. and .com it does nothing, just leaves it as mywebsite.com/mywebsite

Comment: is your htaccess file in your document root? or is this in vhost config?

Comment: That's in my .htaccess file. Finally it seems to be something related to mod_proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your first line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com$ [NC]
```

Comment: That is very odd then as it should be working... But this kind of question should be asked on server fault anyways : )